# django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1292, "Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'incompleted'") django

Tags: python, mysql, django

i tried to change a field type from `CharField` to `BooleanField` , change this

```
completed = _('completed ')
incompleted = _('incompleted ')
payment_status = (
    (completed,completed),
    (incompleted,incompleted),
)

payment_status = models.CharField(max_length=25,choices=payment_status,default=incompleted)
```

to

```
payment_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

`python manage.py makemigrations` created the changed in migrations folders but when i tried to `migrate` it raises this error:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1292, "Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'incompleted'") django

django version : 3.2 , db : mysql

i also tried remove that field but still raise the same error? i dont want to lose my data into my databse

Comment: Try to add a separate field first with a migration (something like `bool_payment_status`), then add a data migration to migrate `payment_status` to `bool_payment_status`, then add another migration to delete the old `payment_status`